# How to see library name loaded with R6034 error?

Tags: manifest

I am getting R6034 error, but can't see the related library/executable since it's name is shortened (see the picture below). Is there any way I can see the full name?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start task manager and go to the "Applications" tab.  The popup should be in that list.

Right-click the window and choose "go to process".  Task manager now jumps to the "processes" tab and shows the process that gives this message.

If you want to find out which DLL is causing the problem, open your executable in Dependency Walker.  If the static analysis of Dependency Walker does not reveal the problem, profile the application in Dependency Walker and look at the profiling output.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I didn't know Dependency Walker can do profiling. I can't check it, because the problem is not more relevant, but I trust your method would work in my case.